# get-release npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, git, modules

Solved, [question with improved code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245878/improved-get-release-npm-module)

I've created a simple npm module and CLI program to get the latest GitHub and Bitbucket release from their APIs using Node.js. Please tell me if there's anything to improve!

#### Module code:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

/**
 * @param {string} string
 * @return {string}
 */
const normalize = (string) => {
    try {
        return string.toUpperCase().trim()
    } catch (e) {
        return string
    }
}

/**
 * @param {string} provider
 * @param {string} user
 * @param {string} repo
 * @param {string} part
 */
module.exports.getRelease = async ({provider, user, repo, part = ""}) => {
    if (normalize(provider) === normalize("github")) {
        let json = (await (await fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/releases/latest`)).json())
        if (json.message === "Not Found") throw "Invalid repository"
        if (!("assets" in json)) throw "Rate limit exceeded"
        let browser_download_urls = json.assets.map(asset => asset.browser_download_url)
        return browser_download_urls.filter(url => url.includes(part))
    } else if (normalize(provider) === normalize("bitbucket")) {
        let json = (await (await fetch(`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${user}/${repo}/downloads/`)).json())
        if (json.type === "error") throw "Invalid repository"
        let links = json.values.map(value => value.links.self.href)
        return links.filter(url => url.includes(part))
    } else {
        throw "Invalid provider"
    }
}

const usage = _ => {
    console.log(
        `Usage: get-release (github|bitbucket) user repo [partofreleasefile]
   Ex: get-release github phhusson treble_experimentations
       get-release github phhusson treble_experimentations arm64-ab-gapps
       get-release bitbucket JesusFreke smali
       get-release bitbucket JesusFreke smali baksmali`
    )
    process.exit(1)
}

// If via CLI
if (require.main === module) {
    let args = process.argv.slice(2)
    if (args.length !== 3 && args.length !== 4) {
        usage()
    }
    module.exports.getRelease({
        provider: args[0],
        user: args[1],
        repo: args[2],
        part: args[3]
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.length !== 1) {
            console.log(result)
        } else {
            console.log(result[0])
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        usage()
        process.exit(1)
    })
}
```

#### Called using:

```js
const { getRelease } = require("get-release")
;(async _ => {
  let url = await getRelease(
      {
          provider: "github",
          user: "phhusson",
          repo: "treble_experimentations",
          part: "arm64-ab-gapps"
      }
  )
  console.log(url[0])
})()
```

Comment: Why the double `await` in `(await (await fetch(`, does it not work with a single `await`?

Comment: @konijn Nope, it doesn't work without the double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a hashmap of provider -> process. This will enable you to register new providers with relative ease.

```
async function githubRelease({user, repo, part = ""}) {
  let json = (await (await fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/releases/latest`)).json())
  if (json.message === "Not Found") throw "Invalid repository"
  if (!("assets" in json)) throw "Rate limit exceeded"
  let browser_download_urls = json.assets.map(asset => asset.browser_download_url)
  return browser_download_urls.filter(url => url.includes(part))
}
```

It will then be mapped inside the `getRelease` function as follows:

```
module.exports.getRelease = async ({provider, user, repo, part = ""}) => {
    if !(providerMethods[normalise(provider)]) {
        throw "Invalid provider"
    }
    return providerMethods[normalise(provider)](user, repo, part)
}
```

where `providerMethods` would be:

```
let providerMethods = {
    normalise("github"): githubReleases
}
```

This will enable users of your module to register new (or private) registry providers. They can add a new provider to the `providerMethods` object (gitlab etc) and don't have to wait for you to update the library first for supporting any extra providers (you can add providers if popular).

The `await (await fetch()).json()` can be extracted to another function. Although, I'd prefer using the `promise.then(r => r.json()).catch()` chain over multiple awaits, it is entirely dependent on your comfort with the language.

Comment: Hi, I've made changes: [Improved code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245878/improved-get-release-npm-module). Thanks for answering!