# (Improved) get-release npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, git, modules

Improved version of [the original question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245718/get-release-npm-module)

I've created a simple npm module and CLI program to get the latest GitHub and Bitbucket release from their APIs using Node.js. Please tell me if there's anything to improve!

[GitHub](https://github.com/KhushrajRathod/get-release) 
[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-release) 
[RunKit](https://npm.runkit.com/get-release)

### Improved module code

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

/**
 * @param {string} string
 * @return {string}
 */
const normalize = (string) => {
    try {
        return string.toUpperCase().trim()
    } catch (e) {
        return string
    }
}

/**
 * @param {string} url
 * @return {string}
 */
const getJSON = async (url) => {
    return (await (await fetch(url)).json())
}

module.exports.providerMethods = {
    GITHUB: async ({user, repo, part = ""}) => {
        let json = await getJSON(`https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/releases/latest`)
        if (json.message === "Not Found") throw "Invalid repository"
        if (!("assets" in json)) throw "Rate limit exceeded"
        let browser_download_urls = json.assets.map(asset => asset.browser_download_url)
        return browser_download_urls.filter(url => url.includes(part))
    },
    BITBUCKET: async ({user, repo, part = ""}) => {
        let json = await getJSON(`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${user}/${repo}/downloads/`)
        if (json.type === "error") throw "Invalid repository"
        let links = json.values.map(value => value.links.self.href)
        return links.filter(url => url.includes(part))
    }
}

/**
 * @param {string} provider
 * @param {string} user
 * @param {string} repo
 * @param {string} part
 */
module.exports.getRelease = async ({provider, user, repo, part = ""}) => {
    if (!(module.exports.providerMethods[normalize(provider)])) {
        throw "Invalid provider"
    }
    return module.exports.providerMethods[normalize(provider)]({user, repo, part})
}

const usage = _ => {
    console.log(
        `Usage: get-release (github|bitbucket) user repo [partofreleasefile]
   Ex: get-release github phhusson treble_experimentations
       get-release github phhusson treble_experimentations arm64-ab-gapps
       get-release bitbucket JesusFreke smali
       get-release bitbucket JesusFreke smali baksmali`
    )
    process.exit(1)
}

// If via CLI
if (require.main === module) {
    let args = process.argv.slice(2)
    if (args.length !== 3 && args.length !== 4) {
        usage()
    }
    module.exports.getRelease({
        provider: args[0],
        user: args[1],
        repo: args[2],
        part: args[3]
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.length !== 1) {
            console.log(result)
        } else {
            console.log(result[0])
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        usage()
        process.exit(1)
    })
}
```

### To be called using

```js
/**
 * Options:
 * {
 *     provider: (github | bitbucket),
 *     user: username,
 *     repo: repository,
 *     part: part of release file name - optional
 * }
 *
 */

const { getRelease, providerMethods } = require("get-release")
;(async _ => {
  let url = await getRelease(
      {
          provider: "github",
          user: "phhusson",
          repo: "treble_experimentations",
          part: "arm64-ab-gapps"
      }
  )
  console.log(url[0])
})()
```

### Custom providers can be defined using

```
const { getRelease, providerMethods } = require("get-release")
providerMethods.GITLAB = async ({user, repo, part = ""}) => {
  // Custom code, should return a string
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've allowed the users to add custom providers, how about hiding the `providerMethods` object itself, and only providing a function which allows them to add to it. This would allow you to also validate if the users' want to override behaviour for predefined providers.

You have a `process.exit(1)` inside the call to `usage()`. Butm when used from cli, you catch all exceptions, then call the `usage` function, and against have another `process.exit(1)`.

The call to usage should not be exiting from the program entirely. It is already handled in case of errors. You can then have a `--help` commandline parameter, which spits out the usage string (without raising an error for the shell).

---

Most of your `if-` conditions use the negated equality check, which is somewhat harder to follow for a developer (at least in my experience). When checking for `args.length`, you have double negation checks. It took me almost a minute to figure out what it is supposed to do. How about applying [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if (!(args.length === 3 || args.length === 4))
```

Or, maybe simply adding a comment?

Also consider:

```
console.log((result.length === 1) ? result[0] : result)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering (again). I don't understand why hiding providerMethods is required. I want users to be able to override the existing providers anyway, and they can add new providers. Is there any advantage to this?

Comment: @KhushrajRathod Since you're releasing this as a package, someone is free to extend/use in their application. Now, if you're providing them access to the `providerMethods` object itself, they may override and cause (un)intentional harm to the end user. Which is why I closed the statement with "_This would allow you to also validate if the users' want to override behaviour for predefined providers_".